# Find all the customer having phone multiple number in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Example:
Lets say I have table `customerphonedetails` ( `customer_no` , `phone_no` ).

```
data is like this :
customer_no =2 Phone_no=11
customer_no =2 Phone_no=12
customer_no =2 Phone_no=13
customer_no =1 Phone_no=11
customer_no =1 Phone_no=12
customer_no =1 Phone_no=13
customer_no =3 Phone_no=22
```

Now I want to write a query which will find the `customer_no` having **all** `phone_no=(11,12,13)`.

Expected result is : Customer_no = (1,2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that all three `Phone_no` provided in the `where` are present for each `customer_no` using `having` clause:

```
select customer_no
from customerphonedetails
where Phone_no in (11, 12, 13)
group by customer_no
having count(distinct Phone_no) = 3
```

Comment: Actually i need customer_no having all ( it is mandatory). Your query will give me customer having phone_no but i want only those customer who has all the three numbers assigned to them. I hope you understand what i am trying to ask ? May be i am not asking in correct way. sorry. –

Comment: @AnkurVerma: the query in the answer does the exact thing you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT customer_no
from table
where phone_no in(11,12,13)
```

It should be remove duplicate record.

Comment: Actually i need customer_no having all ( it is mandatory). Your query will give me customer having phone_no but i want only those customer who has all the three numbers assigned to them. I hope you understand what i am trying to ask ? May be i am not asking in correct way. sorry. –

Comment: Sorry to say Mukesh but your query will not result in correct output because it will give me those customer also who will have either 11,12 or 13. Thanks by the way for reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to perform this:

```
select distinct yes.customer_no
from 
(select  customer_no, count(*) over (partition by customer_no) as how_many_do_you_have
from marcin.marcin) as yes
where yes.how_many_do_you_have = (select count(distinct Phone_no) from marcin.marcin)
```